# Does the recent attack to "the DAO" means end of it?

Tags: security, the-dao, attacks

However implementing *the DAO* and its *smart contracts* are incredibly exciting experiments, the recent attack to *the DAO* clearly suggested that the code is not safe and may or may not have more vulnerabilities.

Is this the end of DAO?

**EDIT:**
Don't get me wrong, bugs are inseparable part of a developers daily life and despite the convenient solution offered by Vitalik, is there any legitimate and effective way to secure the code (even more) and prevent such incidents from happening in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fork code offered by Ethcore puts an end to TheDAO:

> We would like to give you the option to agree on another state of the world. In this state theDAO attacker would not be allowed to take control of the ether inside theDAO - nor would he or she be able to move or spend it. Instead, the DAO tokens will be returned to the Dao token holders, theDAO experiment will end and we will move on wiser.
>
> We will offer you this choice through an optional update to the parity client that will move ether to a recovery contract that will allow DAO token holders to recover their ether. This will maintain consensus with other updates from the Geth team and the CPP team.

https://blog.ethcore.io/attack-on-thedao-what-will-be-your-response/

Miners are free to run this code today if they wish. We don't know yet whether this will end up being the community's decision.

We also have statements from Vitalik:

https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4oj7ql/personal_statement_regarding_the_fork/

and a Geth core dev:

https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4ojsjm/personal_statement_from_one_geth_core_developer/

all of which make clear that it's the community's decision.

Comment: I am not sure how this makes "theDAO experiment" end. Will they not get the money?

Comment: I think they mean return ether to people holding TheDAO tokens, rather than returning it to TheDAO itself.